# c# webbrowser запуск ролика youtube c кнопки

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

Не подскажите возможно ли запустить погруженный ролик с ютуба с кнопки? И если нет, то как можно сделать запрет на клик правой кнопкой мыши, чтобы не появлялось контекстное меню. Отключал контекстное меню, но он все равно выводит.

```
webBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

> как можно сделать запрет на клик правой кнопкой мыши, чтобы не появлялось контекстное меню

Отключить контекстное меню можно обработкой события [HtmlDocument.ContextMenuShowing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.contextmenushowing?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#system-windows-forms-htmldocument-contextmenushowing):

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.ContextMenuShowing += Document_ContextMenuShowing;
}

private void Document_ContextMenuShowing(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    e.ReturnValue = false;
}
```